# A Windows clock to show both UTC and local time?

Tags: windows, taskbar, clock, time-zone, utc

I'm working on windows 7 x64 and searching for a way for a setting, or replacement app of, the tray clock (on the taskbar corner) **to display both [UTC (or GMT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and my [local time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones)**.

Cause: I read log output of several programs realtime, many of them logging in UTC, while meetings (and other people synchronization stuff) is in localtime. Thus I would like to be able to see both local and UTC time in parallel on the system clock. I'm task-switching between many programs, so I'd like it to be always visible.

If I must use a replacement, I would like it to integrate into the taskbar/tray somehow, due not wanting it to cover any screen place that it not occupy fully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One third party app that will allow you to do have both times always shown in the tray is StoicJoker's T-Clock2010:
http://www.stoicjoker.com/tclock/

Edited on 2015-01-27:
Thanks to JourneymanGeek for pointing out that StoicJoker's site is down.
Most recent "incarnation" seems to be this (i did not test this personally, just searched around for 5 minutes):
https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock/releases/tag/v2.3.2%23151-beta
(or to get latest version simply: https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock/releases)
(Find "T-Clock Help.rtf" within the release to get details on how to use time/date functions.)

Comment: +1; even open source, and a most interesting history! I've got it work with Custom Format `ddd\nyyyy/mm/dd\nhh:nn:ss\n"pseudo-utc"\nw-02:nn:ss` (I have plenty much taskbar space set ;).), but this will need to be adjusted manually on [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) changes. Do you have a better idea for the custom format string?

Comment: I accept this one since while the other options are native and great, this one is digital, and it can 'dock' while always visible. The text content is also customizable, although I couldn't handle DST 'The Right Way': needs manual attention on clock advance/retreat (twice a year). But it's open source so one can fix it! :)

Comment: The suggested answer seems down. Is there a mirror somewhere?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Thanks for the hint. I did some googling and found this, which seems to come from stoicjoker. Not sure if it is legit but it seems to provide some answers: http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=21944.0

Answer (score 75):

You can actually accomplish this using the system clock.

1. Click on the tray clock
2. At the bottom, click **Change date and time settings**
3. Click the **Additional Clocks** from the top menu bar
4. Tick **Show this clock** and modify the time zone to suite your needs.
5. Hit **Apply**

Example:

[image]

Comment: Quite nice, didn't notice it (shame on me!) and comes very close to what I wanted. On the nitpick, it's not always visible, one has to hover/click. Wouldn't say it's uncomfortable, but still one step behind of being able to do just a glimpse while reading.

Comment: Does not show on taskbar unless you hover.

Answer (score 14):

Since your using Windows 7 the clock desktop gadget is one option. You can have multiple, name them and make them always on top. There are alternative versions that are more compact with similar settings.

[image: Two Windows 7 desktop clock gadgets]

Comment: setting them always on top, with different skins, gives an easy to spot information at first glance. to problems though: not digital, harder to match logs with; won't dock, so other windows can go under it. I placed it on my second screen for the latter reason. Any idea how to improve on these two points?

Answer (score 4):

When you set up multiple time zones to display with the system clock, then hover your mouse pointer over the system clock's display on the taskbar, you will see all of the clocks that you have set up.

Comment: This would be a better answer if it described *how* to set up multiple time zones — but I realize that it is explained in another answer to this question, and it's not very hard to figure out.