# How can I have a secondary clock show in 24-hour time but the primary one in 12-hour time?

Tags: windows-8.1, time, clock, time-zone

Is it possible to have only one of my [secondary clocks](https://superuser.com/a/649114/375602) display in 24-hour time while the other two clocks display in 12-hour time?  If so, how?

I would find this useful for dealing with UTC time.

<sub>This is not a duplicate of "[Can the Windows clock be configured to display a 24-hour-based time?](https://superuser.com/questions/153787/can-the-windows-clock-be-configured-to-display-a-24-hour-based-time)" as that question is about all clocks in general, while this question is about only one of the additional clocks.</sub>

Comment: Windows does not have this capability.  The format settings apply to every clock.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as the time format setting is applied to every clock.

However, you can easily use a third-party tool to display as many clocks in different settings as you like. One such application is [Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/).